# How to change both table row css when I hover over one row?

Tags: javascript

I have two tables and if I hover on for example second row of first table I want to change css of second row of second table, too. Do you know how?

Can you correct this code?

```
jsfiddle.net/5q7khznL/
```

Comment: Off-topic because User is asking us to correct his code for him.

Answer (score 1):

What have you done so far ? I'm not sure anyone will help you as long as you haven't done some work yourself first.

In Javascript, on the mouse over event of the first table, get the hovered row index, then change the css or class of the corresponding row of the second table. Don't forget to remove the css or class on mouse out.

Answer (score 1):

First you have several elements having the same ID and you should never do this.

Then considering your problem :

You can use .hover() event handler from jquery : http://api.jquery.com/hover/

You just have to fetch the element you want the handler to be applied to and specify what you want to do in the .hover() function arguments.

I suggest you give the same classnames to 1st row of both tables (resp. 2nd row) and apply your changes to these classes on hover.

```
$('.classRow1').css({"background-color":"red"});
```

for example.

Hope this helps

S.P.